Show $f$ is integrable if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\mu(\{x:f(x)>\frac{1}{2^n}\})<\infty$
This is a measure theory qualifying exam question: Suppose $f$ is a bounded nonnegative function on $(X,\mu)$ with $\mu(X)=\infty$. Show that $f$ is integrable if and only if
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\mu\left(\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\frac{1}{2^n}\right\}\right)<\infty$$
This is the question exactly as written on the exam, so there is no more information. I was looking through here and have seen many similar questions, but nearly all of them involved a finite measure space/finite measure. I am speculating that maybe the bounded property on $f$ will "take place" of the finite measure property.
In my attempts, if we assume that $f$ is integrable and define $E_n:=\{x\in X:f(x)>\frac{1}{2^n}\}$, then I believe
\begin{align*}
   \int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\mu(E_n)dx &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^\infty\mu(E_n)dx \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\int_Xf(x)d\mu \\ &= ||f||_{L^1(X)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}<\infty
\end{align*}
We only have that this sum is finite for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in [0,\infty)$ trying the problem this way. I don't believe this is the correct way to go about the problem, but I thought I should share what I have tried so far. Any tips for solving this problem are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Would this still hold if $1/2^n$ is replaced by positive decreasing $a_n$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges?

Does this answer your question? $\int f,d\mu<\infty\Leftrightarrow\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\mu\left(\left{x\in X:f(x)\geq\frac{1}{2^n}\right}\right)<\infty$ or one of this list?https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C OR content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%5Cmu(%5C%7Bx%3Af(x)>%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%5C%7D)<%5Cinfty%24&p=1

@AnneBauval This does look like the same question! I don't know why I couldn't find it upon my first search. Thank you.

@Masacroso I was using proposition 6.24 from Folland's measure theory text book, I believe my result would still hold? I could very well be mistaken in the application though.
